# PHP can not upload file in share folder

Tags: php, upload, shared, samba

I used SAMBA for file sharing in my file server. I mounted the shared folder in my application server. I changed that permission to `0777` and changed owner to Apache user, but I can't upload file in this directory.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @Dave my code is work correctly when i umount that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini :

```
file_uploads=Off

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

After modifying `php.ini` file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

[Document](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)